# Typescript - Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: typescript, casting

I have a type
`export type status = 'success' | 'error' | undefined;`

Now, there is an object that maps to an icon

```
const iconsMap: Record<status, React.ReactSVGElement> = {
  error: ErrorIcon,
  success: SuccessIcon,
};
```

Here, since there is no key `undefined` in iconsMap, it causes a typescript error

`Type 'string | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.`

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could exclude `undefined` using [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility:

```
const iconsMap: Record<NonNullable<status>, React.ReactSVGElement> = {
  error: ErrorIcon,
  success: SuccessIcon,
};
```

---

And formally you get the error not because there is no key `undefined`, but because `Record` has generic type constraint and accepts only `string | number | symbol`.